# Cannot find an overload for "LoadFromText" And the arg count is 2 error is coming in powershell

Tags: powershell, psexec

I'm using psExcel module for converting csv file to excel but I'm getting cannot find an overload for LoadFromText and the argument count is 2.for the following code part in the last line

```
$Format = New-object -TypeName OfficeOpenXml.ExcelTextFormat

$Format.Delimiter = $deli

$Format.TextQualifier = $TextQualifier

$Format.Encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8

$Format.SkipLinesBeginning = ‘0’

$Format.SkipLinesEnd = ‘1’

$ExcelPackage = New-Object OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage

$ExcelPackage.Encryption.IsEncrypted = $false

$Worksheet = $ExcelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add($sheetname) 


$null=$Worksheet.Cells.LoadFromText ((get-item $sheet),$Format)
```

Comment: I think you need to call it on the target cell (eg. the top left corner of the new table): `$Worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromText((Get-Item $sheet).FullName ,$Format)`

Comment: When I tried this it's not adding the csv file data into the excel

Comment: loadfromtext() isn't a powershell function?

Comment: Yes it is powershell function

Comment: It wouldn't be run with the arguments in parentheses and commas then?  `$Worksheet.Cells.LoadFromText (get-item $sheet) $Format `

Comment: What is `$sheet` anyway?

Comment: I can't reproduce your example.  Is $sheetname the name of an excel file?  I just get a null cells property.  $deli and $textqualifier are also unknown.

Comment: Why aren't you using the powershell commands that come with the module?

Comment: I have not uploaded the whole code. I'm new to powershell so can you please tell me which commands I can use?

Comment: I believe this is the same module?  https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSExcel

Comment: ```cannot find an overload for <some method> and the argument count <x>``` can mean (I) there’s no method called ```some method``` on the object, (ii) there’s no overload that takes ```x``` parameters, *or* (iii) there’s a method called ```some method``` that *does* take ```x``` parameters, but you’re calling it with the wrong types. Since ```LoadFromText``` takes a ```string``` and an ```ExcelTextFormat```, try ```$Worksheet.Cells.LoadFromText ((get-item $sheet).Name, $Format)``` instead